# I got error when running appium script in eclipse

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, appium, mobile-automation

> Showing below error while running appium script:

```
Nov 10, 2016 6:27:18 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Nov 10, 2016 6:27:18 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
Nov 10, 2016 6:27:32 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
[Utils] Attempting to create /Users/prasetyo/Documents/workspace/MobileUtandroid/test-output/Default suite/Default test.xml
[Utils]   Directory /Users/prasetyo/Documents/workspace/MobileUtandroid/test-output/Default suite exists: true
```

How to resolve above issue?

Answer (score 2):

Solution -

- This is error occur when you are executing script but there is not default tests are available by default
- You have not mentioned your environment but still I am getting strong feeling if you are using TestNG, cross-check TestNG.xml
- You have missed to create this file or may be that file is empty. So for execution no test are allocated